# RDP vs domain joining

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, domain

Why would you join computers to a domain as opposed to just making everyone RDP to the server?  As I understand it, if you make everyone in an office environment use RDP and use the server as a terminal server environment you only really have to worry about the server for the most part.  But if you join the computers to the domain you have to deal with a lot more work because you have to make sure the pc's are taken care of too.

What am I missing here?  Why do organizations add pc's to the domain vs just making them rdp from their pc to the server?

Comment: There are so many reasons. Too many to cover in a single answer. I suggest you do some research into Windows domains and active directory.

Comment: I mean I understand what a domain is and how active directory works.  What I'm asking is what's the advantage, what's the security hole, why not just use RDP instead?  You're response offers no information and isn't helpful at all.  This says the question is put on hold because it's opinion based... Does this mean there's really no big difference between using RDP vs joining PC's to the domain?  Just whichever way you want to do things for your network environment?  I asked here because I knew I could get answers from people with far more experience than me.  I've only used RDP recently.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but you obviously dont know what a domain is or how active directory works.  The reasons why you would use them and what there advantages are *literally* fill books.  This is the reason the question is too broad.  Not to mention there are limits to RDP.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a company machine I will join it to the domain. I want the user to know they are using company property for one reason. And being joined to the domain makes logging in and accessing shared folders or other company resources less complicated, often the end user can't handle computer network complications.
If it is the users personal machine, and they can pass security, then I generally don't force them to join the domain, but like I said, this can make logging in and accessing shares or other company resources more complicated so the user ends up being schooled about domains and permissions, etc...